# Bayesian network query tool in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, ai

Suppose you are running a business of repairing cars. You know all the parts (graph nodes) and the way they affect other parts (directed edges), and you know the probabilities of each part failing. If the graph of interdependencies between parts is acyclic, it is called a "Bayesian network".

Now suppose a client arrives. You quickly find out the probabilities of each part being in order, yet you see no "Big picture". So you build a Bayesian network using computer and start asking it questions like "If the radio is in order and there is fuel in the car, what is the probability that the car will move?" Answering such questions is exactly what my program attempts to answer.

See what I have:

**BayesNetworkClassifier.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.ai.bayesiannetwork;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

/**
 * This class implements the Bayes network classifier.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 15, 2015)
 */
public class BayesNetworkClassifier {

    private final List<DirectedGraphNode> network;
    private final ProbabilityMap<DirectedGraphNode> probabilityMap;
    private final Map<DirectedGraphNode, Boolean> onoffMap;

    /**
     * Performs the actual classification task.
     * 
     * @param network        the list of (some) nodes of a network to classify.
     * @param probabilityMap the map mapping each node to its probability.
     * @return the data structure that facilitates queries.
     */
    public static ClassificationResult 
        classify(List<DirectedGraphNode> network,
                 ProbabilityMap<DirectedGraphNode> probabilityMap) {

        BayesNetworkClassifier bnc = 
                new BayesNetworkClassifier(network, probabilityMap);

        return bnc.classify();
    }

    /**
     * Implements the actual classification.
     * 
     * @return the classification result structure.
     */
    private ClassificationResult classify() {
        Map<DirectedGraphNode, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
        Set<DirectedGraphNode> set = new TreeSet<>();

        for (DirectedGraphNode node : network) {
            map.put(node, Boolean.FALSE);
        }

        for (DirectedGraphNode node : network) {
            if (node.isIndependent()) {
                set.add(node);
            }
        }

        ClassificationResult result = new ClassificationResult();
        Deque<DirectedGraphNode> tuple = new ArrayDeque<>();
        Set<DirectedGraphNode> visited = new HashSet<>();

        classifyImpl(tuple, visited, set, result, 1.0f);

        return result;

    }

    private boolean nodeHasOffParent(DirectedGraphNode node) {
        for (DirectedGraphNode parent : node.parents()) {
            if (onoffMap.get(parent).equals(Boolean.FALSE)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void classifyImpl(Deque<DirectedGraphNode> tuple,
                              Set<DirectedGraphNode> visited,
                              Set<DirectedGraphNode> levelSet,
                              ClassificationResult result,
                              double probability) {
        if (levelSet.isEmpty()) {
            // End the recursion, record the tuple and its probability as a new
            // system state.
            Map<DirectedGraphNode, Boolean> variableMap = new HashMap<>();

            for (DirectedGraphNode node : tuple) {
                variableMap.put(node, onoffMap.get(node));
            }

            result.addSystemState(new SystemState(variableMap, 
                                                  new ArrayList<>(tuple), 
                                                  probability));
            return;
        }

        Iterator<DirectedGraphNode> iterator = levelSet.iterator();

        // Remove the nodes from 'levelSet' whose some parents are not yet
        // processed.
        outer:
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            for (DirectedGraphNode parent : iterator.next().parents()) {
                if (!visited.contains(parent)) {
                    iterator.remove();
                    continue outer;
                }
            }
        }

        // Set of nodes whose on/off status cannot vary.
        Set<DirectedGraphNode> skipSet = new HashSet<>(levelSet.size());

        for (DirectedGraphNode node : levelSet) {
            if (nodeHasOffParent(node) || probabilityMap.get(node) == 0.0) {
                onoffMap.put(node, Boolean.FALSE);
                skipSet.add(node);
            } else if (probabilityMap.get(node) == 1.0) {
                onoffMap.put(node, Boolean.TRUE);
                skipSet.add(node);
            }
        }

        DirectedGraphNode[] nodeArray = new DirectedGraphNode[levelSet.size() -
                                                               skipSet.size()];

        int i = 0;

        // Add the level to visited set.
        for (DirectedGraphNode node : levelSet) {
            if (!skipSet.contains(node)) {
                nodeArray[i++] = node;
            }

            visited.add(node);

            if (tuple.size() < visited.size()) {
                tuple.addLast(node);
            }

            if (result.getNodeList().size() < visited.size()) {
                result.getNodeList().add(node);
            }
        }

        Set<DirectedGraphNode> nextLevelSet = new TreeSet<>();

        // Compute the next node level.
        for (DirectedGraphNode node : levelSet) {
            for (DirectedGraphNode child : node.children()) {
                nextLevelSet.add(child);
            }
        }

        boolean doInit = true;

        while (getNextCombination(nodeArray, doInit)) {
            doInit = false;

            classifyImpl(tuple, 
                         visited, 
                         nextLevelSet, 
                         result, 
                         probability * computeProbability(nodeArray));
        }

        // Clean up the state for further recursion.
        for (DirectedGraphNode node : levelSet) {
            visited.remove(node);
        }
    }

    private double computeProbability(DirectedGraphNode[] nodeArray) {
        double p = 1.0;

        for (DirectedGraphNode node : nodeArray) {
            if (onoffMap.get(node).equals(Boolean.TRUE)) {
                p *= probabilityMap.get(node);
            } else {
                p *= 1.0 - probabilityMap.get(node);
            }
        }

        return p;
    }

    private boolean getNextCombination(DirectedGraphNode[] nodes, 
                                       boolean doInit) {
        if (doInit) {
            for (DirectedGraphNode node : nodes) {
                onoffMap.put(node, Boolean.FALSE);
            }

            return true;
        }

        for (int i = nodes.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            if (onoffMap.get(nodes[i]).equals(Boolean.FALSE)) {
                onoffMap.put(nodes[i], Boolean.TRUE);

                for (++i; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
                    onoffMap.put(nodes[i], Boolean.FALSE);
                }

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Constructs the internal state of the classifier.
     * 
     * @param network        the list of (some) nodes in the Bayes network.
     * @param probabilityMap the map mapping each node to its probability.
     */
    private BayesNetworkClassifier(
            List<DirectedGraphNode> network,
            ProbabilityMap<DirectedGraphNode> probabilityMap) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(network, "The input network is null.");
        Objects.requireNonNull(probabilityMap, 
                               "The input probability map is null.");

        checkNetworkNotEmpty(network);
        network = Utils.findEntireGraph(network.get(0));
        checkNetworkIsAcyclic(network);
        checkProbabilityMap(probabilityMap, network);

        this.network = network;
        this.probabilityMap = probabilityMap;
        this.onoffMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (DirectedGraphNode node : network) {
            onoffMap.put(node, Boolean.FALSE);
        }
    }

    private static void checkNetworkNotEmpty(List<DirectedGraphNode> network) {
        if (network.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The input network is empty.");
        }
    }

    private static void checkNetworkIsAcyclic(List<DirectedGraphNode> network) {
        if (!Utils.graphIsAcyclic(network.get(0))) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The input network contains cycles.");
        }
    }

    private static void checkProbabilityMap(
            ProbabilityMap<DirectedGraphNode> probabilityMap,
            List<DirectedGraphNode> nodeList) {
        for (DirectedGraphNode node : nodeList) {
            if (!probabilityMap.contains(node)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "The node " + node + " is not mapped in the probability map.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ClassificationResult.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.ai.bayesiannetwork;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * This class implements the classification result of the Bayes network.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.61 (Sep 16, 2015)
 */
public class ClassificationResult {

    private final List<SystemState> systemStateList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<DirectedGraphNode> nodeList = new ArrayList<>();

    public double query(Map<DirectedGraphNode, Boolean> posterioriVariableMap,
                        Map<DirectedGraphNode, Boolean> aprioriVariableMap) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(posterioriVariableMap, 
                               "The posteriori variable map is null.");
        Objects.requireNonNull(aprioriVariableMap,
                               "The apriori variable map is null.");

        if (mapKeyIntersect(posterioriVariableMap, aprioriVariableMap)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Posteriori and apriori variable list have a common " +
                     "variable.");
        }

        Map<DirectedGraphNode, Boolean> combinedVariableMap = 
                new HashMap<>(posterioriVariableMap);

        combinedVariableMap.putAll(aprioriVariableMap);

        double aprioriProbability    = 0.0;
        double posterioriProbability = 0.0;

        for (SystemState state : systemStateList) {
            if (state.stateContainsSubstate(aprioriVariableMap)) {
                aprioriProbability += state.getProbability();

                if (state.stateContainsSubstate(combinedVariableMap)) {
                    posterioriProbability += state.getProbability();
                }
            }
        }

        return posterioriProbability == 0.0 ? 0.0 : posterioriProbability / 
                                                    aprioriProbability;
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the sum of probabilities over all system states, and
     * it <b>must</b> return <b>1.0</b> under any circumstances.
     * 
     * @return the sum of probabilities.
     */
    public double getSumOfProbabilities() {
        double probability = 0.0;

        for (SystemState state : systemStateList) {
            probability += state.getProbability();
        }

        return probability;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(");
        int i = 0;

        for (DirectedGraphNode node : nodeList) {
            sb.append(node);

            if (i < nodeList.size() - 1) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }

            ++i;
        }

        sb.append(")\n");

        for (SystemState state : systemStateList) {
            sb.append(state).append('\n');
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    void addSystemState(SystemState state) {
        systemStateList.add(state);
    }

    List<DirectedGraphNode> getNodeList() {
        return nodeList;
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the two input maps have common keys.
     * 
     * @param <K>  the key type.
     * @param <V>  the value type.
     * @param map1 the first map.
     * @param map2 the second map.
     * @return {@code true} if maps share at least one common key.
     */
    private static <K, V> boolean mapKeyIntersect(Map<K, V> map1, 
                                                  Map<K, V> map2) {
        Map<K, V> smallerMap;
        Map<K, V> largerMap;

        if (map1.size() < map2.size()) {
            smallerMap = map1;
            largerMap  = map2;
        } else {
            smallerMap = map2;
            largerMap  = map1;
        }

        for (K key : smallerMap.keySet()) {
            if (largerMap.containsKey(key)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**SystemState.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.ai.bayesiannetwork;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * This class encodes a particular state of the Bayes network and its 
 * probability.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.61 (Sep 16, 2015)
 */
final class SystemState {

    private final Map<DirectedGraphNode, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
    private final List<DirectedGraphNode> nodeList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final double probability;

    SystemState(Map<DirectedGraphNode, Boolean> map, 
                List<DirectedGraphNode> nodeList,
                double probability) {
        this.map.putAll(map);
        this.nodeList.addAll(nodeList);
        this.probability = probability;
    }

    boolean stateContainsSubstate(
            Map<DirectedGraphNode, Boolean> substate) {
        for (Map.Entry<DirectedGraphNode, Boolean> entry : 
                substate.entrySet()) {
            if (!entry.getValue().equals(map.get(entry.getKey()))) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    double getProbability() {
        return probability;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(");
        int i = 0;

        for (DirectedGraphNode node : nodeList) {
            int fieldLength = node.toString().length();
            String field = String.format("%" + fieldLength + "s",
                                         map.get(node) ? "1" : "0");
            sb.append(field);

            if (i < nodeList.size() - 1) {
                sb.append(", ");
                i++;
            }
        }

        return sb.append("): ")
                 .append(probability)
                 .toString();
    }
}
```

**App.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.ai.bayesiannetwork;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * This class implements a console program for working on Bayes networks.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 15, 2015)
 */
public class App {

    /**
     * This map maps each node name to its internal representation.
     */
    private final Map<String, DirectedGraphNode> nodeMap = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * This map maps each node to its probability.
     */
    private final ProbabilityMap<DirectedGraphNode> probabilityMap =
            new ProbabilityMap<>();

    private boolean stateModified = true;
    private ClassificationResult result;

    private void loop() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (;;) {
            System.out.print("> ");

            if (!scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                // Most probably the input was redirected, print no "Bye!".
                return;
            }

            String commandLine = scanner.nextLine().trim();

            if (commandLine.isEmpty()) {
                // No text in the command line.
                continue;
            }

            if (commandLine.equals("quit")) {
                break;
            }

            String[] words = commandLine.split("\\s+");

            switch (words[0]) {
                case "node": {
                    handleNodeCommand(words);
                    break;
                }

                case "connect": {
                    handleConnectCommand(words);
                    break;
                }

                case "disconnect": {
                    handleDisconnectCommand(words);
                    break;
                }

                case "print": {
                    handlePrintCommand();
                    break;
                } 

                default: {
                    if (words[0].startsWith("p(")) {
                        tryQuery(commandLine);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(
                                "Unknown command: \"" + commandLine + "\".");
                    }   
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Bye!");
    }

    private void tryQuery(String line) {
        if (!line.startsWith("p(")) {
            return;
        }

        if (!line.endsWith(")")) {
            System.out.println("No trailing \")\".");
            return;
        }

        String innerContent = line.substring(2, line.length() - 1).trim();
        String[] parts = innerContent.split("\\|");

        if (parts.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("Error: No single delimeter bar |");
            return;
        }

        Map<DirectedGraphNode, Boolean> posterioriVariables = new HashMap<>();
        Map<DirectedGraphNode, Boolean> aprioriVariables = new HashMap<>();

        String[] posterioriVarStrings = parts[0].split(",");
        String[] aprioriVarStrings = parts[1].split(",");

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < posterioriVarStrings.length; ++i) {
                posterioriVarStrings[i] = posterioriVarStrings[i].trim();
                boolean negate = false;
                String varName;

                if (posterioriVarStrings[i].startsWith("not ")) {
                    negate = true;
                    varName = posterioriVarStrings[i].substring(4);
                } else {
                    varName = posterioriVarStrings[i];
                }

                if (!nodeMap.containsKey(varName)) {
                    System.out.println("Error: no node \"" + varName + "\".");
                    return;
                } 

                posterioriVariables.put(nodeMap.get(varName), !negate);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < aprioriVarStrings.length; ++i) {
                aprioriVarStrings[i] = aprioriVarStrings[i].trim();
                boolean negate = false;
                String varName;

                if (aprioriVarStrings[i].startsWith("not ")) {
                    negate = true;
                    varName = aprioriVarStrings[i].substring(4);
                } else {
                    varName = aprioriVarStrings[i];
                }

                if (!nodeMap.containsKey(varName)) {
                    System.out.println("Error: no node \"" + varName + "\".");
                    return;
                }

                aprioriVariables.put(nodeMap.get(varName), !negate);
            }

            System.out.println(result.query(posterioriVariables, aprioriVariables));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void handleNodeCommand(String[] words) {
        if (words.length == 1) {
            System.out.println("Error: no node name given.");
            return;
        } 

        String nodeName = words[1].trim();

        if (!nodeMap.containsKey(nodeName)) {
            if (words.length == 2) {
                System.out.println("Node \"" + nodeName + "\" is not defined.");
                return;
            }

            // Try to add a new node.
            double newProbability;

            try {
                newProbability = Double.parseDouble(words[2]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Error: " + words[2] + " is an invalid probability.");
                return;
            }

            try {
                DirectedGraphNode newnode = new DirectedGraphNode(words[1]);
                nodeMap.put(nodeName, newnode);
                probabilityMap.put(newnode, newProbability);
                stateModified = true;
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
                nodeMap.remove(words[1]);
            }

            return;
        } else {
            if (words.length == 2) {
                // Print the current probability of a node.
                System.out.println(probabilityMap.get(nodeMap.get(nodeName)));
            } else if (words.length > 2) {
                // Update the probability.
                double newProbability;

                try {
                    newProbability = Double.parseDouble(words[2]);
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    System.out.println(
                            "Error: misspelled probability: " + words[2]);
                    return;
                }

                try {
                    probabilityMap.put(nodeMap.get(nodeName), newProbability);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleConnectCommand(String[] words) {
        if (words.length < 4 || !words[2].equals("to")) {
            System.out.println("Bad format. Use \"connect <tail> to <head>\"");
            return;
        }

        String tailNodeName = words[1];
        String headNodeName = words[3];

        if (!nodeMap.containsKey(tailNodeName)) {
            System.out.println("Error: \"" + words[1] + "\", no such node.");
            return;
        }

        if (!nodeMap.containsKey(headNodeName)) {
            System.out.println("Error: \"" + words[1] + "\", no such node.");
            return;
        }

        DirectedGraphNode tail = nodeMap.get(tailNodeName);
        DirectedGraphNode head = nodeMap.get(headNodeName);

        if (tail.hasChild(head)) {
            return;
        }

        tail.addChild(head);
        stateModified = true;
    }

    private void handleDisconnectCommand(String[] words) {
        if (words.length < 4 || !words[2].equals("from")) {
            System.out.println("Bad format. Use \"connect <tail> to <head>\"");
            return;
        }

        String tailNodeName = words[1];
        String headNodeName = words[3];

        if (!nodeMap.containsKey(tailNodeName)) {
            System.out.println("Error: \"" + words[1] + "\", no such node.");
            return;
        }

        if (!nodeMap.containsKey(headNodeName)) {
            System.out.println("Error: \"" + words[1] + "\", no such node.");
            return;
        }

        DirectedGraphNode tail = nodeMap.get(tailNodeName);
        DirectedGraphNode head = nodeMap.get(headNodeName);

        if (!tail.hasChild(head)) {
            return;
        }

        tail.removeChild(head);
        stateModified = true;
    }

    private void handlePrintCommand() {
        if (stateModified) {
            List<DirectedGraphNode> network = new ArrayList<>(nodeMap.values());

            try {
                result = BayesNetworkClassifier.classify(network, probabilityMap);
                stateModified = false;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
                return;
            }
        }

        if (result == null) {
            System.out.println("Error: no network built yet.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
        app.loop();
    }
}
```

**Utils.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.ai.bayesiannetwork;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class contains various utility methods.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 15, 2015)
 */
public class Utils {

    /**
     * Given the start node {@code start}, this static method treats each 
     * directed arc as an undirected arc, and crawls entire graph reachable from
     * {@code start}.
     * 
     * @param  start the node whose graph we want to crawl.
     * @return the list of nodes reachable from {@code start} if each directed
     *         arc is considered to be undirected.
     */
    public static List<DirectedGraphNode> 
        findEntireGraph(DirectedGraphNode start) {
        Deque<DirectedGraphNode> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
        Set<DirectedGraphNode> visited = new HashSet<>();

        queue.addLast(start);
        visited.add(start);

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            DirectedGraphNode current = queue.removeFirst();

            for (DirectedGraphNode child : current.children()) {
                if (!visited.contains(child)) {
                    visited.add(child);
                    queue.addLast(child);
                }
            }

            for (DirectedGraphNode parent : current.parents()) {
                if (!visited.contains(parent)) {
                    visited.add(parent);
                    queue.addLast(parent);
                }
            }
        }

        return new ArrayList<>(visited);
    }

    public static boolean graphIsAcyclic(DirectedGraphNode start) {
        List<DirectedGraphNode> nodeList = findEntireGraph(start);
        Map<DirectedGraphNode, NodeColor> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (DirectedGraphNode node : nodeList) {
            map.put(node, NodeColor.WHITE);
        }

        for (DirectedGraphNode node : nodeList) {
            if (dfs(node, map)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private enum NodeColor {
        WHITE,
        GRAY,
        BLACK
    }

    /**
     * Implements the cycle detection algorithm.
     * 
     * @param node the node to start the search from.
     * @param map  the color map.
     * @return {@code true} if there is a cycle in the graph. {@code false} 
     *         otherwise.
     */
    private static boolean dfs(DirectedGraphNode node, 
                               Map<DirectedGraphNode, NodeColor> map) {
        map.put(node, NodeColor.GRAY);

        for (DirectedGraphNode child : node.children()) {
            if (map.get(child).equals(NodeColor.WHITE)) {
                // The color of 'child' is WHITE.
                if (dfs(child, map)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            if (map.get(child).equals(NodeColor.GRAY)) {
                // Found a cycle.
                return true;
            }
        }

        map.put(node, NodeColor.BLACK);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The above classes are the ones I want to receive critique on. If you want to run the entire program, clone from [github](https://github.com/coderodde/BayesianNetworkQuery) and invoke `mvn exec:java`.

Also, a demonstration input:

```
node B 0.9  # Battery
node R 0.9  # Radio
node I 0.95 # Ignition
node F 0.95 # Fuel 
node S 0.99 # Starts
node M 0.99 # Moves
connect B to R
connect B to I
connect I to S
connect F to S
connect S to M
print
p(B | not M, not S)
p(not B | not S)
```