# Binary Bayes network classifier in Java - Part I/II

Tags: java, console

I was working on the binary Bayesian network classifier I [asked about earlier](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104727/bayesian-network-query-tool-in-java).

See also [Part II/II](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105042/binary-bayes-network-classifier-in-java-part-ii).

See also the [next iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105080/binary-bayes-network-classifier-in-java-part-i-follow-up) of Part I.

**TERMINOLOGY**
We are given a directed *acyclic* graph (dag) \$G = (V, A)\$, where \$V\$ is the set of nodes and \$A \subseteq V \times V\$ is the set of directed **arcs**, and a weight function \$p \colon V \to [0, 1]\$. For any node \$u \in V\$, \$parents(u) =\{v \in V \colon (v, u) \in A\}\$, which is a set of parent (or incoming) nodes of \$u\$. Now, each node \$u\$ corresponds to some part that "works" with probability \$p(u)\$ and "fails" with probability \$1 - p(u)\$. However, if any such \$u\$ has a non-empty set of parents and at least one of the parents failed, \$u\$ fails unconditionally.

**MISSION** I wrote a REPL (read, evaluate, print, loop) program, which allows its users to build a binary Bayesian network and perform queries on it; for example, `p(not Radio, Battery | not Moves, Ignition)`, or "what is the probability that radio does not work and battery does work if we know that ignition is in order and the car does not move.

**SAMPLE INPUT**

```
# Create nodes.
new Battery  0.9  # Comment
new Radio    0.9  
new Ignition 0.95
new Fuel     0.95
new Starts   0.99
new Moves    0.99

# Print a node.
Fuel
del Fuel
echo Removed Fuel
Fuel
new Fuel 0.95

# Create arcs.
connect Battery  to Radio
connect Battery  to Ignition
connect Ignition to Starts
connect Fuel     to Starts
connect Starts   to Moves

# Check a couple of arcs.
echo Battery connected to Radio?
is Battery connected to Radio   # Must be 'true'.
echo Radio connected to Battery?
is Radio   connected to Battery # Must be 'false'.

# Remove an arc (Battery, Radio).
disconnect Battery from Radio
echo Removed arc (Battery, Radio).
echo Is Battery connected to Radio?
is Battery connected to Radio
connect Battery to Radio

# Print a couple of nodes.
Battery
Starts
Radio

# List all possible system states with their probabilities.
list

# Try a couple of queries.
p(Battery|not Moves, not Starts)
p(not Battery| not Starts)

# Show help.
help
help is connected

# Make the graph disonnected.
disconnect Ignition from Starts
echo Here, the graph must not be connected.
list

quit
echo You must not see this message.
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
"Fuel", probability 0.95, parents: <>, children: <>
Removed Fuel
ERROR: "Fuel": no such node.
Battery connected to Radio?
true
Radio connected to Battery?
false
Removed arc (Battery, Radio).
Is Battery connected to Radio?
false
"Battery", probability 0.9, parents: <>, children: <Ignition, Radio>
"Starts", probability 0.99, parents: <Ignition, Fuel>, children: <Moves>
"Radio", probability 0.9, parents: <Battery>, children: <>
Compiled the graph in 7 milliseconds.
Number of possible states: 14
(Battery, Fuel, Ignition, Radio, Starts, Moves)
(      0,    0,        0,     0,      0,     0): 0.005000000000000004
(      0,    1,        0,     0,      0,     0): 0.09499999999999997
(      1,    0,        0,     0,      0,     0): 2.2500000000000037E-4
(      1,    0,        0,     1,      0,     0): 0.002025000000000004
(      1,    0,        1,     0,      0,     0): 0.004275000000000003
(      1,    0,        1,     1,      0,     0): 0.03847500000000003
(      1,    1,        0,     0,      0,     0): 0.004275000000000003
(      1,    1,        0,     1,      0,     0): 0.03847500000000003
(      1,    1,        1,     0,      0,     0): 8.122500000000005E-4
(      1,    1,        1,     0,      1,     0): 8.041275000000005E-4
(      1,    1,        1,     0,      1,     1): 0.07960862249999998
(      1,    1,        1,     1,      0,     0): 0.007310250000000006
(      1,    1,        1,     1,      1,     0): 0.007237147500000006
(      1,    1,        1,     1,      1,     1): 0.7164776024999999
0.4894638093657867
0.5105361906342133
  help new
  help del
  help connect
  help is connected
  help disconnect
  help list
  help echo
  help #
  help <nodename>
  help p
  help quit
"is <tailnode> connected to <headnode>"
Asks whether <tailnode> has a child <headnode>.
Here, the graph must not be connected.
ERROR: The graph is not connected.
```

**App.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.ai.bayesiannetwork;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static net.coderodde.ai.bayesiannetwork.BayesNetworkClassifier.classify;
import static net.coderodde.ai.bayesiannetwork.Utils.findEntireGraph;

/**
 * This class implements a console program for working on Bayes networks.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.61 (Sep 18, 2015)
 */
public class App {

    /**
     * This map maps each node name to its internal representation.
     */
    private final Map<String, DirectedGraphNode> nodeMap = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * This map maps each node to its probability.
     */
    private final ProbabilityMap<DirectedGraphNode> probabilityMap =
            new ProbabilityMap<>();

    /**
     * Indicates whether the state of the graph was changed after last
     * compilation.
     */
    private boolean stateModified = true;

    /**
     * Caches the last classification result for queries.
     */
    private ClassificationResult result;

    /**
     * This method implements the actual REPL (Read, Evaluate, Print, Loop).
     * 
     * @param fileNames the array containing the names of the files to execute.
     *                  This array may be null, in which case the program reads
     *                  from the console. If array is not {@code null}, executes
     *                  the files in the order they appear in the array.
     */
    private void loop(String[] fileNames) {
        Scanner scanner;
        boolean turnOffPrompt;
        int fileNameIndex = 0;

        if (fileNames != null) {
            try {
                scanner = new Scanner(
                          new FileReader(
                          new File(fileNames[fileNameIndex])));

                fileNameIndex++;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                error("File \"" + fileNames[fileNameIndex] + "\" not found.");
                return;
            }

            turnOffPrompt = true;
        } else {
            scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            turnOffPrompt = false;
        }

        for (;;) {
            if (!turnOffPrompt) {
                System.out.print("> ");
            }

            if (!scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                // Here, we possibly have that a file was read in its entirety.
                // What next? Proceed to executing the next file, or if there is 
                // no such, go read from the standard input.
                if (fileNames != null) {
                    if (fileNameIndex == fileNames.length) {
                        // Once here, we have executed all files on the command
                        // line. Switch to reading from stdin.
                        fileNames = null;
                        turnOffPrompt = false;
                        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                        System.out.print("> ");
                    } else {
                        try {
                            scanner = new Scanner(
                                      new FileReader(
                                      new File(fileNames[fileNameIndex])));
                            fileNameIndex++;
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                            error("File \"" + fileNames[fileNameIndex] + 
                                  "\" not found.");
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }

            String command = scanner.nextLine().trim();

            if (command.isEmpty()) {
                // No text in the command.
                continue;
            }

            if (command.equals("quit")) {
                if (fileNames != null) {
                    // Print no 'Bye!' whenever executing from files.
                    return;
                }

                break;
            }

            if (command.startsWith("#")) {
                // A comment line.
                continue;
            }

            // Obtain whitespace delimited tokens.
            String[] words = command.split("\\s+");

            // Choose the command by the first token.
            switch (words[0]) {
                case "new": {
                    handleNew(words);
                    continue;
                }

                case "del": {
                    handleDel(words);
                    continue;
                }

                case "connect": {
                    handleConnect(words);
                    continue;
                }

                case "disconnect": {
                    handleDisconnect(words);
                    continue;
                }

                case "list": {
                    handleList(true);
                    continue;
                }

                case "is": {
                    handleIs(words);
                    continue;
                }

                case "echo": {
                    handleEcho(command);
                    continue;
                }

                case "help": {
                    handleHelp(words); 
                    continue;
                }
            }

            if (handleQuery(command)) {
                // Once here, the command was recognized as a query, so go 
                // reiterate the REPL loop.
                continue;
            }

            // No match whatsoever, possibly the user wants to query a node 
            // information.
            handlePrintNode(words);
        }

        System.out.println("Bye!");
    }

    /**
     * Checks that an identifier is a valid Java identifier.
     * 
     * @param identifier the identifier to check.
     * @return {@code true} only if the input identifier is valid.
     */
    private static boolean isValidIdentifier(String identifier) {
        if (identifier.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(identifier.charAt(0))) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < identifier.length(); ++i) {
            if (!Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(identifier.charAt(i))) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Handles the command starting with "new".
     * @param words the token array.
     */
    private void handleNew(String[] words) {
        if (words.length < 3) {
            error("Cannot parse 'new' command.");
            return;
        }

        if (words.length >= 4 && !words[3].startsWith("#")) {
            error("Bad comment format.");
            return;
        }

        String nodeName = words[1];
        String probabilityString = words[2];

        if (!isValidIdentifier(nodeName)) {
            error("\"" + nodeName + "\" is a bad node identifier.");
            return;
        }

        double probability;

        try {
            probability = Double.parseDouble(probabilityString);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            error("Cannot parse \"" + probabilityString + 
                  "\" as a probability value.");
            return;
        }

        if (Double.isNaN(probability)) {
            error("Input probability is NaN.");
            return;
        }

        if (probability < 0.0) {
            error("Probability is too small.");
            return;
        }

        if (probability > 1.0) {
            error("Probability is too large.");
            return;
        }

        // Associate (or reassociate) the node with the probability value.
        DirectedGraphNode node;

        if (nodeMap.containsKey(nodeName)) {
            node = nodeMap.get(nodeName);
            probabilityMap.put(node, probability);
        } else {
            node = new DirectedGraphNode(nodeName);
            nodeMap.put(nodeName, node);
        }

        probabilityMap.put(node, probability);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the command for deleting a node.
     * 
     * @param words the array of tokens.
     */
    private void handleDel(String[] words) {
        if (words.length < 2) {
            error("Missing the name of the node to delete.");
            return;
        }

        String nodeName = words[1];

        if (!isValidIdentifier(nodeName)) {
            error("\"" + nodeName + "\" is not a valid node name.");
            return;
        }

        DirectedGraphNode removed = nodeMap.remove(nodeName);

        if (removed != null) {
            removed.clear();
            probabilityMap.remove(removed);
            stateModified = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the command for creating arcs between nodes.
     * 
     * @param words the array of tokens.
     */
    private void handleConnect(String[] words) {
        if (words.length < 4) {
            error("Missing required tokens.");
            return;
        }

        if (!words[2].equals("to")) {
            error("Format error.");
            return;
        }

        String tailNodeName = words[1];
        String headNodeName = words[3];

        if (!isValidIdentifier(tailNodeName)) {
            error("Bad tail node name: \"" + tailNodeName + "\".");
            return;
        }

        if (!isValidIdentifier(headNodeName)) {
            error("Bad head node name: \"" + headNodeName + "\".");
            return;
        }

        if (!nodeMap.containsKey(tailNodeName)) {
            error("No node with name \"" + tailNodeName + "\".");
            return;
        }

        if (!nodeMap.containsKey(headNodeName)) {
            error("No node with name \"" + headNodeName + "\".");
            return;
        }

        if (tailNodeName.equals(headNodeName)) {
            error("Self-loops not allowed.");
            return;
        }

        DirectedGraphNode tail = nodeMap.get(tailNodeName);
        DirectedGraphNode head = nodeMap.get(headNodeName);

        if (!tail.hasChild(head)) {
            tail.addChild(head);
            stateModified = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the command for removing arcs between nodes.
     * 
     * @param words the array of tokens.
     */
    private void handleDisconnect(String[] words) {
        if (words.length < 4) {
            error("Missing required tokens.");
            return;
        }

        if (!words[2].equals("from")) {
            error("Format error.");
            return;
        }

        String tailNodeName = words[1];
        String headNodeName = words[3];

        if (!isValidIdentifier(tailNodeName)) {
            error("Bad tail node name: \"" + tailNodeName + "\".");
            return;
        }

        if (!isValidIdentifier(headNodeName)) {
            error("Bad head node name: \"" + headNodeName + "\".");
            return;
        }

        if (!nodeMap.containsKey(tailNodeName)) {
            error("No node with name \"" + tailNodeName + "\".");
            return;
        }

        if (!nodeMap.containsKey(headNodeName)) {
            error("No node with name \"" + headNodeName + "\".");
            return;
        }

        if (tailNodeName.equals(headNodeName)) {
            return;
        }

        DirectedGraphNode tail = nodeMap.get(tailNodeName);
        DirectedGraphNode head = nodeMap.get(headNodeName);

        if (tail.hasChild(head)) {
            tail.removeChild(head);
            stateModified = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the command for querying the existence of arcs between particular
     * nodes.
     * 
     * @param words the array of tokens.
     */
    private void handleIs(String[] words) {
        if (words.length < 5
                || !words[2].equals("connected")
                || !words[3].equals("to")) {
            error("Bad format.");
            return;
        }

        String tailNodeName = words[1];
        String headNodeName = words[4];

        if (!isValidIdentifier(tailNodeName)) {
            error("Bad tail node name \"" + tailNodeName + "\".");
            return;
        }

        if (!isValidIdentifier(headNodeName)) {
            error("Bad head node name \"" + headNodeName + "\".");
            return;
        }

        if (!nodeMap.containsKey(tailNodeName)) {
            error("No node \"" + tailNodeName + "\"");
            return;
        }

        if (!nodeMap.containsKey(headNodeName)) {
            error("No node \"" + headNodeName + "\"");
            return;
        }

        DirectedGraphNode tail = nodeMap.get(tailNodeName);
        DirectedGraphNode head = nodeMap.get(headNodeName);

        System.out.println(tail.hasChild(head));
    }

    /**
     * Handles the command for listing the system states.
     * 
     * @param showList whether to show the actual state list after successful
     *                 compilation.
     */
    private void handleList(boolean showList) {
        if (stateModified) {
            List<DirectedGraphNode> network = new ArrayList<>(nodeMap.values());

            if (network.isEmpty()) {
                error("You have no nodes.");
                return;
            }

            List<DirectedGraphNode> component = findEntireGraph(network.get(0));

            if (component.size() < network.size()) {
                error("The graph is not connected.");
                return; 
            }

            try {
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                result = BayesNetworkClassifier.classify(network, 
                                                         probabilityMap);
                long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                stateModified = false;

                System.out.println("Compiled the graph in " + 
                                  (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds.");
                if (Math.abs(1.0 - result.getSumOfProbabilities()) > 0.0001) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "The sum of probabilities over all possible states does " + 
                    "not sum to 1.0");
                }

                System.out.println("Number of possible states: " +
                                   result.getNumberOfStates());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                error(ex.getMessage());
                return;
            }
        }

        if (result == null) {
            error("No network built yet.");
        } else if (showList) {
            System.out.print(result);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the command for printing to the console.
     * 
     * @param command the command.
     */
    private void handleEcho(String command) {
        String leftovers = command.substring(4).trim();
        System.out.println(leftovers);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the commands for making queries on the network.
     * 
     * @param command the command.
     * @return {@code true} if command prefix is that of query commands.
     */
    private boolean handleQuery(String command) {
        if (!command.startsWith("p(")) {
            return false;
        }

        if (stateModified) {
            handleList(false);

            if (stateModified) {
                // If 'handleList' could not update the state, we have a problem
                // with the graph: it is either disconnected or contains cycles.
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (!command.endsWith(")")) {
            error("No trailing \")\".");
            return true;
        }

        String innerContent = command.substring(2, command.length() - 1).trim();
        String[] parts = innerContent.split("\\|");

        if (parts.length != 2) {
            error("No single delimeter bar |");
            return true;
        }

        Map<DirectedGraphNode, Boolean> posterioriVariables = new HashMap<>();
        Map<DirectedGraphNode, Boolean> aprioriVariables = new HashMap<>();

        String[] posterioriVarStrings = parts[0].split(",");
        String[] aprioriVarStrings = parts[1].split(",");

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < posterioriVarStrings.length; ++i) {
                posterioriVarStrings[i] = posterioriVarStrings[i].trim();
                boolean negate = false;
                String varName;

                if (posterioriVarStrings[i].startsWith("not ")) {
                    negate = true;
                    varName = posterioriVarStrings[i].substring(4);
                } else {
                    varName = posterioriVarStrings[i];
                }

                if (!nodeMap.containsKey(varName)) {
                    error("No node \"" + varName + "\".");
                    return true;
                } 

                posterioriVariables.put(nodeMap.get(varName), !negate);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < aprioriVarStrings.length; ++i) {
                aprioriVarStrings[i] = aprioriVarStrings[i].trim();
                boolean negate = false;
                String varName;

                if (aprioriVarStrings[i].startsWith("not ")) {
                    negate = true;
                    varName = aprioriVarStrings[i].substring(4);
                } else {
                    varName = aprioriVarStrings[i];
                }

                if (!nodeMap.containsKey(varName)) {
                    error("No node \"" + varName + "\".");
                    return true;
                }

                aprioriVariables.put(nodeMap.get(varName), !negate);
            }

            if (stateModified) {
                try {
                    result = classify(new ArrayList<>(nodeMap.values()), 
                                      probabilityMap);

                    if (result != null) {
                        stateModified = false;
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    error(ex.getMessage());
                    return true;
                }
            }

            System.out.println(result.query(posterioriVariables, 
                                            aprioriVariables));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            error(ex.getMessage());
            return true;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Handles the command for printing a node information.
     * 
     * @param words the array of tokens.
     */
    private void handlePrintNode(String[] words) {
        if (words.length > 1 && !words[1].startsWith("#")) {
            error("Bad command.");
            return;
        }

        if (!nodeMap.containsKey(words[0])) {
            error("\"" + words[0] + "\": no such node.");
            return;
        }

        DirectedGraphNode node = nodeMap.get(words[0]);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;

        // Get parent node names.
        for (DirectedGraphNode parent : node.parents()) {
            sb.append(parent);

            if (i++ < node.parents().size() - 1) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
        }

        String parentListString = sb.toString();

        sb.delete(0, sb.length());
        i = 0;

        // Get child node names.
        for (DirectedGraphNode child : node.children()) {
            sb.append(child);

            if (i++ < node.children().size() - 1) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
        }

        String childListString = sb.toString();

        System.out.println(
                "\"" + words[0] + "\", probability " + 
                probabilityMap.get(node) + ", parents: <" + parentListString +
                ">, children: <" + childListString + ">");
    }

    /**
     * Handles the command for printing the help information.
     * 
     * @param words the array of tokens.
     */
    private void handleHelp(String[] words) {
        if (words.length > 3) {
            error("The syntax for \"help\" command is \"help [keywords]\".");
            return;
        } else if (words.length == 3) {
            if (!words[1].equals("is") || !words[2].equals("connected")) {
                error("The syntax for \"help\" command is " +
                      "\"help [keywords]\".");
                return;
            }
        }

        if (words.length == 1) {
            System.out.println("  help new");
            System.out.println("  help del");
            System.out.println("  help connect");
            System.out.println("  help is connected");
            System.out.println("  help disconnect");
            System.out.println("  help list");
            System.out.println("  help echo");
            System.out.println("  help #");
            System.out.println("  help <nodename>");
            System.out.println("  help p");
            System.out.println("  help quit");
            return;
        }

        switch (words[1]) {
            case "new": {
                System.out.println("\"new <nodename> <probability>\"");
                System.out.println("Creates a new node with name <nodename> " +
                                   "and probability <probability>.");
                break;
            }

            case "del": {
                System.out.println("\"del <nodename>\"");
                System.out.println("Deletes the node with name <nodename>.");
                break;
            }

            case "connect": {
                System.out.println("\"connect <tailnode> to <headnode>\"");
                System.out.println("Creates an arc from <tailnode> to " +
                                   "<headnode>.");
                break;
            }

            case "is": {
                if (words.length != 3) {
                    System.out.println(
                            "ERROR: No help topic. Did you mean " +
                            "\"help is connected\"?");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(
                            "\"is <tailnode> connected to <headnode>\"");
                    System.out.println("Asks whether <tailnode> has a child " +
                                       "<headnode>.");
                }

                break;
            }

            case "disconnect": {
                System.out.println("\"disconnect <tailnode> from <headnode>\"");
                System.out.println("Removes an arc from <tailnode> to " +
                                   "<headnode>.");
                break;
            }

            case "list": {
                System.out.println("\"list\"");
                System.out.println("Lists all the possible system states.");
                break;
            }

            case "echo": {
                System.out.println("\"echo [<text>]\"");
                System.out.println("Prints <text> to the console.");
                break;
            }

            case "#": {
                System.out.println("\"# [<text>]\"");
                System.out.println("Starts a line comment.");
                break;
            }

            case "p": {
                System.out.println(
                        "\"p(<posterioriVariables> | " +
                        "<aprioriVariables>)\"");
                System.out.println("Makes a query.");
                System.out.println("EXAMPLE 1: p(not var1 | var2, not var3)");
                System.out.println("EXAMPLE 2: p(var 1 | var2)");
                System.out.println(".");
                System.out.println(".");
                System.out.println(".");
                break;
            }

            case "<nodename>": {
                System.out.println("\"<nodename>\"");
                System.out.println("Print the node information.");
                break;
            }

            case "quit": {
                System.out.println("\"quit\"");
                System.out.println("Quits the program.");
                break;
            }

            default: {
                System.out.println(
                        "ERROR: Unknown topic: \"" + words[1] + "\"");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns {@code true} if at least one of the input strings is "-h".
     * 
     * @param args the strings to check.
     * @return {@code true} if at least one of the strings is "-h".
     */
    private static boolean hasHelpFlag(String[] args) {
        for (String argument : args) {
            if (argument.trim().equals("-h")) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (hasHelpFlag(args)) {
            System.out.println(
                    "java -jar <PROGRAM.jar> [-h] [FILE1 FILE2 ... FILEN]");
            return;
        }

        App app = new App();

        if (args.length == 0) {
            app.loop(null);
        } else {
            app.loop(args);
        }
    }

    private static void error(String message) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: " + message);
    }
}
```

**CRITIQUE REQUEST**
In what ways can I improve my code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I like comments. I like Javadoc. But comments that say *what* are suspicious - good comments say *why*, not *what*. Given self-explanatory code, Javadoc on private members is overkill: you have Javadoc *everywhere*, and it's distracting.

---

> ```
> /**
>  * This method implements the actual REPL (Read, Evaluate, Print, Loop).
>  * 
>  * @param fileNames the array containing the names of the files to execute.
>  *                  This array may be null, in which case the program reads
>  *                  from the console. If array is not {@code null}, executes
>  *                  the files in the order they appear in the array.
>  */
> private void loop(String[] fileNames) {
> ```

The method has **outrageous** cyclomatic complexity, is breaking the *Single Responsibility Principle* (SRP) *by design*, and is poorly named - granted, naming a method that's *doing 4 things* is certainly a hard thing to do. But given `read`, `evaluate`, `print` and `loop`, I really wonder why a method that does all 4 would simply be called `loop`.

Speaking of loops:

```
for (;;) {
```

Clearly you're abusing the `for` construct here. A more idiomatic "infinite loop" would be `while (true)`.