# Binary Bayes network classifier in Java - Part II/II

Tags: java, algorithm, ai

This is the continuation of [Binary Bayes network classifier in Java - Part I/II](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105041/binary-bayes-network-classifier-in-java-part-i-ii)

**TERMINOLOGY**
We are given a directed *acyclic* graph (dag) \$G = (V, A)\$, where \$V\$ is the set of nodes and \$A \subseteq V \times V\$ is the set of directed **arcs**, and a weight function \$p \colon V \to [0, 1]\$. For any node \$u \in V\$, \$parents(u) =\{v \in V \colon (v, u) \in A\}\$, which is a set of parent (or incoming) nodes of \$u\$. Now, each node \$u\$ corresponds to some part that "works" with probability \$p(u)\$ and "fails" with probability \$1 - p(u)\$. However, if any such \$u\$ has a non-empty set of parents and at least one of the parents failed, \$u\$ fails unconditionally.

**MISSION** I wrote a REPL (read, evaluate, print, loop) program, which allows its users to build a binary Bayesian network and perform queries on it; for example, `p(not Radio, Battery | not Moves, Ignition)`, or "what is the probability that radio does not work and battery does work if we know that ignition is in order and the car does not move.

This question presents the actual algorithm implementation.

**BayesNetworkClassifier.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.ai.bayesiannetwork;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

/**
 * This class implements the binary Bayes network classifier.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.61 (Sep 18, 2015)
 */
public class BayesNetworkClassifier {

    private final List<DirectedGraphNode> network;
    private final ProbabilityMap<DirectedGraphNode> probabilityMap;
    private final Map<DirectedGraphNode, Boolean> onoffMap;
    private final ClassificationResult result;
    private final Set<DirectedGraphNode> visited;
    private final List<DirectedGraphNode> tuple;

    /**
     * Performs the actual classification task.
     * 
     * @param network        the list of (some) nodes of a network to classify.
     * @param probabilityMap the map mapping each node to its probability.
     * @return the data structure that facilitates queries.
     */
    public static ClassificationResult 
        classify(List<DirectedGraphNode> network,
                 ProbabilityMap<DirectedGraphNode> probabilityMap) {
        BayesNetworkClassifier bnc = 
                new BayesNetworkClassifier(network, probabilityMap);

        return bnc.classify();
    }

    /**
     * Constructs the internal state of the classifier.
     * 
     * @param network        the list of (some) nodes in the Bayes network.
     * @param probabilityMap the map mapping each node to its probability.
     */
    private BayesNetworkClassifier(
            List<DirectedGraphNode> network,
            ProbabilityMap<DirectedGraphNode> probabilityMap) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(network, "The input network is null.");
        Objects.requireNonNull(probabilityMap, 
                               "The input probability map is null.");

        checkNetworkNotEmpty(network);
        network = Utils.findEntireGraph(network.get(0));
        checkNetworkIsAcyclic(network);
        checkProbabilityMap(probabilityMap, network);

        this.network = network;
        this.probabilityMap = probabilityMap;
        this.onoffMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (DirectedGraphNode node : network) {
            onoffMap.put(node, Boolean.FALSE);
        }

        this.result = new ClassificationResult();
        this.visited = new HashSet<>(network.size());
        this.tuple = new ArrayList<>(network.size());
    }

    /**
     * Implements the actual classification.
     * 
     * @return the classification result structure.
     */
    private ClassificationResult classify() {
        classify(getRootSet(network), 1.0f);
        result.setNodeList(tuple);
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the set of nodes that have no parents.
     * 
     * @param network the Bayes network to process.
     * @return the set of root nodes.
     */
    private Set<DirectedGraphNode> getRootSet(List<DirectedGraphNode> network) {
        Set<DirectedGraphNode> set = new TreeSet<>();

        for (DirectedGraphNode node : network) {
            if (isIndependent(node)) {
                set.add(node);
            }
        }

        return set;
    }

    /**
     * Returns {@code true} if the input node has a parent whose current state 
     * is "off".
     * 
     * @param node the node to check.
     * @return {@code true} if the input node has a turned off parent.
     */
    private boolean nodeHasOffParent(DirectedGraphNode node) {
        for (DirectedGraphNode parent : node.parents()) {
            if (onoffMap.get(parent).equals(Boolean.FALSE)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Implements the actual compilation from a Bayesian network to the list of
     * system states. This algorithm builds a tree whose leafs are all possible 
     * system states, yet it prunes the search by skipping the nodes whose state
     * cannot vary, thus implementing "branch-and-bound" technique.
     * 
     * @param levelSet    the set of nodes on current level.
     * @param probability the accumulated probability.
     */
    private void classify(Set<DirectedGraphNode> levelSet,
                          double probability) {
        if (levelSet.isEmpty()) {
            // End the recursion, record the tuple and its probability as a new
            // system state.
            Map<DirectedGraphNode, Boolean> variableMap = new HashMap<>();

            for (DirectedGraphNode node : tuple) {
                variableMap.put(node, onoffMap.get(node));
            }

            result.addSystemState(new SystemState(variableMap, 
                                                  result, 
                                                  probability));
            return;
        }

        Iterator<DirectedGraphNode> iterator = levelSet.iterator();

        // Remove the nodes from 'levelSet' whose some parents are not yet
        // processed. We will get to them in deeper recursion depth.
        outer:
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            for (DirectedGraphNode parent : iterator.next().parents()) {
                if (!visited.contains(parent)) {
                    iterator.remove();
                    continue outer;
                }
            }
        }

        // Set of nodes whose on/off status cannot vary, namely the nodes whose
        // probability is 0 or whose some parents are off, or nodes with no off
        // parents and probability 1.0.
        Set<DirectedGraphNode> skipSet = new HashSet<>(levelSet.size());

        for (DirectedGraphNode node : levelSet) {
            if (nodeHasOffParent(node) || probabilityMap.get(node) == 0.0) {
                onoffMap.put(node, Boolean.FALSE);
                skipSet.add(node);
            } else if (probabilityMap.get(node) == 1.0) {
                onoffMap.put(node, Boolean.TRUE);
                skipSet.add(node);
            }
        }

        DirectedGraphNode[] nodeArray = new DirectedGraphNode[levelSet.size() -
                                                               skipSet.size()];

        int i = 0;

        // Add the level to visited set and load the node at current level that
        // can vary.
        for (DirectedGraphNode node : levelSet) {
            if (!skipSet.contains(node)) {
                nodeArray[i++] = node;
            }

            visited.add(node);

            if (tuple.size() < visited.size()) {
                tuple.add(node);
            }
        }

        Set<DirectedGraphNode> nextLevelSet = new TreeSet<>();

        // Compute the next node level.
        for (DirectedGraphNode node : levelSet) {
            for (DirectedGraphNode child : node.children()) {
                nextLevelSet.add(child);
            }
        }

        boolean doInit = true;

        // For each combination of variable state nodes, recur.
        while (getNextCombination(nodeArray, doInit)) {
            doInit = false;

            classify(nextLevelSet,
                         probability * computeProbability(nodeArray));
        }

        // Clean up the state for further recursion.
        for (DirectedGraphNode node : levelSet) {
            visited.remove(node);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Computes the probability of configuration consisting of nodes in 
     * {@code nodeArray}.
     * 
     * @param nodeArray the array of nodes whose probabilities to accumulate.
     * @return the probability value.
     */
    private double computeProbability(DirectedGraphNode[] nodeArray) {
        double p = 1.0;

        for (DirectedGraphNode node : nodeArray) {
            if (onoffMap.get(node).equals(Boolean.TRUE)) {
                p *= probabilityMap.get(node);
            } else {
                p *= 1.0 - probabilityMap.get(node);
            }
        }

        return p;
    }

    /**
     * Generates the next combination of states for nodes in {@code nodes}.
     * 
     * @param nodes  the array of nodes for which we want to generate all 
     *               possible states.
     * @param doInit indicate whether the states should be all initialized to 
     *               "off".
     * @return {@code false} if upon entry to this method all states in 
     *         {@code nodes} is "on", which indicates there is no more state
     *         combinations.
     */
    private boolean getNextCombination(DirectedGraphNode[] nodes, 
                                       boolean doInit) {
        if (doInit) {
            for (DirectedGraphNode node : nodes) {
                onoffMap.put(node, Boolean.FALSE);
            }

            return true;
        }

        for (int i = nodes.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            if (onoffMap.get(nodes[i]).equals(Boolean.FALSE)) {
                onoffMap.put(nodes[i], Boolean.TRUE);

                for (++i; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
                    onoffMap.put(nodes[i], Boolean.FALSE);
                }

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static void checkNetworkNotEmpty(List<DirectedGraphNode> network) {
        if (network.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The input network is empty.");
        }
    }

    private static void checkNetworkIsAcyclic(List<DirectedGraphNode> network) {
        if (!Utils.graphIsAcyclic(network.get(0))) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The current network contains cycles.");
        }
    }

    private static void checkProbabilityMap(
            ProbabilityMap<DirectedGraphNode> probabilityMap,
            List<DirectedGraphNode> nodeList) {
        for (DirectedGraphNode node : nodeList) {
            if (!probabilityMap.contains(node)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "The node " + node + " is not mapped in the probability map.");
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isIndependent(DirectedGraphNode node) {
        return node.parents().isEmpty();
    }
}
```

**DirectedGraphNode.java**

```
package net.coderodde.ai.bayesiannetwork;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class implements directed graph nodes.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 14, 2015)
 */
public class DirectedGraphNode implements Comparable<DirectedGraphNode> {

    private final String name;
    private final Set<DirectedGraphNode> children = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    private final Set<DirectedGraphNode> parents  = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public DirectedGraphNode(String name) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(name, "The node name is null.");
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addChild(DirectedGraphNode child) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(child, "The child node is null.");

        if (child == this) {
            return;
        }

        children.add(child);
        child.parents.add(this);
    }

    public boolean hasChild(DirectedGraphNode child) {
        return children.contains(child);
    }

    public void removeChild(DirectedGraphNode child) {
        if (children.contains(child)) {
            children.remove(child);
            child.parents.remove(this);
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        for (DirectedGraphNode child : children) {
            child.parents.remove(this);
        }

        for (DirectedGraphNode parent : parents) {
            parent.children.remove(this);
        }

        children.clear();
        parents.clear();
    }

    public Set<DirectedGraphNode> children() {
        return Collections.<DirectedGraphNode>unmodifiableSet(children);
    }

    public Set<DirectedGraphNode> parents() {
        return Collections.<DirectedGraphNode>unmodifiableSet(parents);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(DirectedGraphNode other) {
        return name.compareTo(other.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof DirectedGraphNode)) {
            return false;
        }

        return name.equals(((DirectedGraphNode) o).name);
    }
}
```

**Utils.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.ai.bayesiannetwork;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class contains various utility methods.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 15, 2015)
 */
public class Utils {

    /**
     * Given the start node {@code start}, this static method treats each 
     * directed arc as an undirected arc, and crawls entire graph reachable from
     * {@code start}.
     * 
     * @param  start the node whose graph we want to crawl.
     * @return the list of nodes reachable from {@code start} if each directed
     *         arc is considered to be undirected.
     */
    public static List<DirectedGraphNode> 
        findEntireGraph(DirectedGraphNode start) {
        Deque<DirectedGraphNode> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
        Set<DirectedGraphNode> visited = new HashSet<>();

        queue.addLast(start);
        visited.add(start);

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            DirectedGraphNode current = queue.removeFirst();

            for (DirectedGraphNode child : current.children()) {
                if (!visited.contains(child)) {
                    visited.add(child);
                    queue.addLast(child);
                }
            }

            for (DirectedGraphNode parent : current.parents()) {
                if (!visited.contains(parent)) {
                    visited.add(parent);
                    queue.addLast(parent);
                }
            }
        }

        return new ArrayList<>(visited);
    }

    /**
     * Checks that the entire graph reachable from {code start} is acyclic.
     * 
     * @param start a representative node of a graph.
     * @return {@code true} only if the graph has directed cycles.
     */
    public static boolean graphIsAcyclic(DirectedGraphNode start) {
        List<DirectedGraphNode> nodeList = findEntireGraph(start);
        Map<DirectedGraphNode, NodeColor> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (DirectedGraphNode node : nodeList) {
            map.put(node, NodeColor.WHITE);
        }

        for (DirectedGraphNode node : nodeList) {
            if (dfs(node, map)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private enum NodeColor {
        WHITE,
        GRAY,
        BLACK
    }

    /**
     * Implements the cycle detection algorithm, which is depth-first search.
     * 
     * @param node the node to start the search from.
     * @param map  the color map.
     * @return {@code true} if there is a cycle in the graph. {@code false} 
     *         otherwise.
     */
    private static boolean dfs(DirectedGraphNode node, 
                               Map<DirectedGraphNode, NodeColor> map) {
        map.put(node, NodeColor.GRAY);

        for (DirectedGraphNode child : node.children()) {
            if (map.get(child).equals(NodeColor.WHITE)) {
                // The color of 'child' is WHITE.
                if (dfs(child, map)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            if (map.get(child).equals(NodeColor.GRAY)) {
                // Found a cycle.
                return true;
            }
        }

        map.put(node, NodeColor.BLACK);
        return false;
    }
}
```

**ProbabilityMap.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.ai.bayesiannetwork;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * This class maps objects to their probabilities.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 15, 2015)
 * @param <T> the object implementation type.
 */
public class ProbabilityMap<T> {

    private final Map<T, Double> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void put(T object, double probability) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(object, "The input node is null.");
        checkProbability(probability);
        map.put(object, probability);
    }

    public double get(T node) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(node, "The query node is null.");

        if (!map.containsKey(node)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "There is no mapping for node " + node);
        }

        return map.get(node);
    }

    public boolean contains(T node) {
        return map.containsKey(node);
    }

    public void remove(T object) {
        map.remove(object);
    }

    private static void checkProbability(double probability) {
        if (Double.isNaN(probability)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The input probability is NaN.");
        }

        if (probability < 0.0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The input probability is too small: " + probability);
        }

        if (probability > 1.0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The input probability is too large: " + probability);
        }
    }
}
```

**ClassificationResult.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.ai.bayesiannetwork;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * This class implements the classification result of the Bayes network.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.618 (Sep 18, 2015)
 */
public class ClassificationResult {

    private final List<SystemState> systemStateList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<DirectedGraphNode> nodeList;

    /**
     * Computes the probability of posteriori variables given the apriori
     * variables.
     * 
     * @param posterioriVariableMap a map mapping each posteriori variable to 
     *                              its state.
     * @param aprioriVariableMap    a map mapping each apriori variable to its
     *                              state.
     * @return the probability of expression.
     */
    public double query(Map<DirectedGraphNode, Boolean> posterioriVariableMap,
                        Map<DirectedGraphNode, Boolean> aprioriVariableMap) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(posterioriVariableMap, 
                               "The posteriori variable map is null.");
        Objects.requireNonNull(aprioriVariableMap,
                               "The apriori variable map is null.");

        if (mapKeyIntersect(posterioriVariableMap, aprioriVariableMap)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Posteriori and apriori variable lists have a common " +
                     "variable.");
        }

        Map<DirectedGraphNode, Boolean> combinedVariableMap = 
                new HashMap<>(posterioriVariableMap);

        combinedVariableMap.putAll(aprioriVariableMap);

        double aprioriProbability    = 0.0;
        double posterioriProbability = 0.0;

        for (SystemState state : systemStateList) {
            if (state.stateContainsSubstate(aprioriVariableMap)) {
                aprioriProbability += state.getProbability();

                if (state.stateContainsSubstate(combinedVariableMap)) {
                    posterioriProbability += state.getProbability();
                }
            }
        }

        return aprioriProbability == 0.0 ? 0.0 : posterioriProbability / 
                                                 aprioriProbability;
    }

    void setNodeList(List<DirectedGraphNode> nodeList) {
        this.nodeList = nodeList;
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the sum of probabilities over all system states, and
     * it <b>must</b> return <b>1.0</b> under any circumstances.
     * 
     * @return the sum of probabilities.
     */
    public double getSumOfProbabilities() {
        double probability = 0.0;

        for (SystemState state : systemStateList) {
            probability += state.getProbability();
        }

        return probability;
    }

    public int getNumberOfStates() {
        return systemStateList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(");
        int i = 0;

        for (DirectedGraphNode node : nodeList) {
            sb.append(node);

            if (i < nodeList.size() - 1) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }

            ++i;
        }

        sb.append(")\n");

        for (SystemState state : systemStateList) {
            sb.append(state).append('\n');
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    void addSystemState(SystemState state) {
        systemStateList.add(state);
    }

    List<DirectedGraphNode> getNodeList() {
        return nodeList;
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the two input maps have common keys.
     * 
     * @param <K>  the key type.
     * @param <V>  the value type.
     * @param map1 the first map.
     * @param map2 the second map.
     * @return {@code true} if maps share at least one common key.
     */
    private static <K, V> boolean mapKeyIntersect(Map<K, V> map1, 
                                                  Map<K, V> map2) {
        Map<K, V> smallerMap;
        Map<K, V> largerMap;

        if (map1.size() < map2.size()) {
            smallerMap = map1;
            largerMap  = map2;
        } else {
            smallerMap = map2;
            largerMap  = map1;
        }

        for (K key : smallerMap.keySet()) {
            if (largerMap.containsKey(key)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**SystemState.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.ai.bayesiannetwork;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class encodes a particular state of the Bayes network and its 
 * probability.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.618 (Sep 18, 2015)
 */
final class SystemState {

    /**
     * The set of nodes in this state whose state is "on". All nodes in the
     * network that are not in this list are considered to have state "off". 
     */
    private final Set<DirectedGraphNode> onSet = new HashSet<>();

    /**
     * The probability of this state.
     */
    private final double probability;

    /**
     * The {@code ClassificationResult} this state belongs to.
     */
    private final ClassificationResult owner;

    SystemState(Map<DirectedGraphNode, Boolean> map, 
                ClassificationResult result,
                double probability) {
        for (Map.Entry<DirectedGraphNode, Boolean> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().equals(Boolean.TRUE)) {
                onSet.add(entry.getKey());
            }
        }

        this.probability = probability;
        this.owner = result;
    }

    boolean stateContainsSubstate(Map<DirectedGraphNode, Boolean> substate) {
        for (Map.Entry<DirectedGraphNode, Boolean> entry : 
                substate.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue()) {
                if (!onSet.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                if (onSet.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    double getProbability() {
        return probability;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(");
        List<DirectedGraphNode> nodeList = owner.getNodeList();
        int i = 0;

        for (DirectedGraphNode node : nodeList) {
            int fieldLength = node.toString().length();
            String field = String.format("%" + fieldLength + "s",
                                         onSet.contains(node) ? "1" : "0");
            sb.append(field);

            if (i < nodeList.size() - 1) {
                sb.append(", ");
                i++;
            }
        }

        return sb.append("): ")
                 .append(probability)
                 .toString();
    }
}
```

How can I improve this?